# Trying to sort an ArrayList using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, comparator

In the code below the object `someObj` has two properties, a `float x` and an `int pnt`.
An `ArrayList<someObj>` is created and is then sorted using a `Comparator` interface according to x. The property `pnt` is intended to keep track of the elements after the sorting.

I've copied the code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-sort-java-examples/
and modified it a little to suit my needs. I wonder what might be wrong, it just does not do its sorting job.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayListSorting {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       // 20 random numbers will be used for the test
       final int sz=20;
       Random rand = new Random();
       
       ArrayList<someObj> oList=new ArrayList<someObj>();
      
      // Build the list
      for(int i=0;i<sz;i++) {
          oList.add(new someObj(i,rand.nextFloat()));
      }
    
      // Print the list before sorting
      for(int i=0;i<sz;i++) {
          System.out.println(i+"\t"+oList.get(i).getX());
      }

      Collections.sort(oList, new sorter());

      // ...and after sorting
      for(int i=0;i<sz;i++) {
          int j=oList.get(i).getPnt();
          System.out.println(j+"\t"+oList.get(i).getX());
      }

   }
}

class someObj {

    private float x;
    private int pnt;
    
    public someObj(int pnt,float x) {
        this.pnt=pnt;
        this.x=x;
    }
    
    public int getPnt() {
        return pnt;
    }
    
    public float getX() {
        return x;
    }
}

class sorter implements Comparator<someObj> {
    
    public int compare(someObj a, someObj b) {
        return (int)(a.getX() - b.getX());
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code exactly?

Comment: I does not sort, but after some debugging I have replaced the line: return (int)(a.getX() - b.getX()); by: return (int)Math.signum(a.getX() - b.getX()); and now it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nextFloat()` will generate a `float` in the range [0,1), and by subtracting any two such values in the comparator, you'll get a value in the range (-1, 1). When you cast this to an `int` you'll get a 0, meaning that according to this comparator they are all equivalent, and the list will retain its order.

You can solve this by not implementing the comparator with `-`, but by reusing `Float`'s [`compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,float)) method:

```java
class sorter implements Comparator<someObj> {
    
    public int compare(someObj a, someObj b) {
        return Float.compare(a.getX(), b.getX());
    }
}
```

Or better yet, use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)) to create this comparator on the fly:

```java
Collections.sort(oList, Comparator.comparing(someObj::getX));
```

**EDIT:**
As Andy Turner noted in the comments, `Collections.sort` is a bit outdated. Since JDK 8, lists have their own `sort` method you can invoke directly:

```java
oList.sort(Comparator.comparing(someObj::getX));
```

Comment: Also, note that `Collections.sort(oList, comparator)` invokes `oList.sort(comparator)`; so you may as well just invoke it directly.

Comment: @AndyTurner I was sticking with the OP's style, but you're right, might as well note that too. Edited.